# Xubuntu 13.10 And Ubuntu 13.10 both show WPA Supplicant error?

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, wpa-supplicant, wpa

Why am I getting this error. How do I fix it?

```
sudo lshw -C network
*-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 74:e5:43:f2:18:cd
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.11.0-12-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.154 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:f7d00000-f7d7ffff memory:f7d80000-f7d8ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.2
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.2
       logical name: eth0
       version: 0a
       serial: 08:60:6e:04:ac:b6
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-1_0.0.3 06/18/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:42 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
```

Using ifconfig:

```
 ifconfig
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:60:6e:04:ac:b6  
              UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
              inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
              inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
              UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
              RX packets:2644 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:2644 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:243135 (243.1 KB)  TX bytes:243135 (243.1 KB)

    wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:e5:43:f2:18:cd  
              inet addr:192.168.1.154  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::76e5:43ff:fef2:18cd/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:253274 errors:0 dropped:2 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:134379 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:348427070 (348.4 MB)  TX bytes:13362722 (13.3 MB)
```

Error Message:

http://s16.postimg.org/6vtwca0v9/Screenshot_10312013_08_07_03_PM.png

http://s12.postimg.org/cwcw0ydl9/Screenshot_10312013_08_07_57_PM.png

Comment: I receive the same error on a lenovo yoga 2 with Ubuntu 13:10

Comment: @Ben DeMott any solutions?

Answer (score -1):

The following command seems to fix the error, well at least at first reboot the error does not appear.

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp
```

I hope this helps.